# CSV file to list of lines?

Tags: python, csv

I have a txt file and I want to save each line as a list in a new file with fname as the new file name. But the output is not being saved. What am I missing?

```
import csv

with open('file.txt', 'rU') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    i = 1
    for line in reader:
        fname = line[0] + line[1]
        #print fname
        with open(fname, 'w') as out:
            out.write(line)
        i +=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you want, you need to fix two things, one is to open the output files in "append" mode so their previous contents aren't wiped-out everytime something additional is written to them.

Secondly you need some way to know the raw data from the file for each csv row it reads. This can be difficult when you use an extension like the `csv` module and don't know the internals (which you shouldn't use anyway).

To work around that in this case, you can pass a custom `csvfile` argument to the `csv.reader` that will give you the information needed. Basically a small preprocessor of the data being read. Here's what I mean:

```
import csv

def pre_reader(file):
    """Generator that remembers last line read."""
    for line in file:
        pre_reader.lastline = line
        yield line

with open('test_gen.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(pre_reader(csvfile), delimiter='\t')
    i = 1
    for line in reader:
        fname = line[0] + line[1]
        #print fname
        with open(fname, 'a') as out:
            out.write(pre_reader.lastline)
        i +=1
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and for the explanation!

Comment: You're welcome. Note, too, that instead of manually counting the lines read using `i = 0` plus the `i += 1` in the `for` loop, you could just use: `for i, line in enumerate(reader):` which will automatically count them for you.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
with open(fname, 'w') as out:
            out.write(line)
```

To:

```
with open(fname, 'a') as out:
        out.write(line)
```

**w**   Opens a file for writing only. **Overwrites** the file if the file exists. If the file does not exist, creates a new file for writing.

**a**   Opens a file for appending. The file pointer is at the end of the file if the file exists. That is, the file is in the append mode. If the file does not exist, it creates a new file for writing.

Better way:

```
import csv

with open('file.txt', 'rU') as csvfile, open(fname, 'w') as out:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    i = 1
    for line in reader:
        fname = line[0] + line[1]
        out.write(line)
```

Comment: This doesn't work as line splits each line from the file into a list.  Cannot write a list

Answer (score -1):

You cannot write a list so change penultimate line to `**out.write(str(line))**`

```
import csv

with open('file.txt', 'rU') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    i = 1
    for line in reader:
        fname = line[0] + line[1]
        #print fname
        with open(fname, 'w') as out:
 ------>    out.write(str(line))
        i +=1
```

Comment: Why are you opening the file inside the loop?